# Is there a shortkey to mark a reminder as being done in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

In the Reminder Tab in Evernote Evernote only lists it's global hotkeys.
Is there any shortcut in Evernote to mark the reminder of a note as being done?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, no. To bad...
But i would like to see this too and [found a feature Request in the forum](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/56041-feature-request-want-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-adding-and-editing-reminders/?locale=de)

-> https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/56041-feature-request-want-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-adding-and-editing-reminders/?locale=de